# One time circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I have very little knowledge about build my own electronics.
However I've decided to prototype an idea I have.

I'll have to fit the device into a small cylinder (dia. 15mm, height 10-20 mm.). It also needs to be simple and cheap.

What this little thing should do:

- The battery is plugged in (3V CR1025)
- A LED is turned on
- A button is pushed
- The LED turns off
- The button is released
- The LED is turned on
- It should no longer be possible to turn off the LED unless battery is removed

I was hoping you guys could me with a diagram and a component list. From my research I *THINK* I need:

- CR1025 battery
- LED diode
- SMD NO switch
- Transistor
- Fuse or SMD relay

Am I correct and how do I find out which specs I need for the components?

Thanks.

Comment: This site  is meant to help people with problems related to electrical engineering.  It is not a design service. In any event, it would be more helpful if you described the purpose of your device so that suggestions on how to achieve your goals may be given.

Comment: Sounds like a broken flashlight to me.

Comment: Hi Barry. I know it's not a design service, but I thought someone could maybe help out. I can put things together, but I'm on thin ice on this topic.

Comment: Are you no longer interested in this?

Comment: @Blair, I'm still interested. I'll review the answers later today. Thanks :)

Comment: [Are you not entertained](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/20/20dc7825d07c77cf179e08b58cdfaf736e09542908cb9a1dfd07bbbc900f35ec.jpg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. It's very simple with a few basic logic gates:

- D-flip flop (CD4013)
- Not (CD4069)
- Or (CD4071)

**Behavioral Schematic**
[image: schematic behavioral]

**Functional Schematic**
[image: schematic functional]

**How it works**

On power up, the clock of stage 1, or *S1*, is initialized low by the inverter. *Q̅* of S1, or *S1(Q̅)*, is initially high. The LED, therefore, defaults on since *S1(Q̅)* is fed through the *OR* gate to the LED anode.

When the button is pressed (which is debounced by the 10 kΩ resistor and 1 µF capacitor) the clock of *S1*, or *S1(C)*, goes from low to high causing the high value on its *D* input to be transferred to its *Q* output, and a low value to its *Q̅* output. The low value at *Q̅* subsequently turns the LED off.

At the same time, while the button is held, *S2(C)* is lowered.

When the button is released, *S2(C)* goes from low to high, transferring the high value of *S1(Q)* to *S2(Q)*, which turns the LED back on.

At this point, both registers will continue to hold high values irrespective of the switch, and the LED will remain on indefinitely, until the power is removed.

This satisfies all of your requirements:

> - The battery is plugged in (3V CR1025)
> - A LED is turned on
> - A button is pushed
> - The LED turns off
> - The button is released
> - The LED is turned on
> - It should no longer be possible to turn off the LED unless battery is removed

**Circuit simulation**

[image: otc circuit simulation]

Here's the VHDL (not necessary for building the circuit, of course)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Engineer: Blair Fonville
-- Create Date: 07/13/2017 05:27:35 PM
-- Design Name: one time circuit
-- Module Name: otc - Behavioral
-- Description: SE.engineering
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity otc is
 --   Port ();
end otc;

architecture Behavioral of otc is

    -- input, output
    signal push_button : std_logic := '0';
    signal led         : std_logic;

    -- dff
    signal stage1      : std_logic := '0';
    signal stage2      : std_logic := '0';
begin

    ----------------------
    -- CIRCUIT
    ----------------------
    led <= not stage1 or stage2;

    process(push_button)
    begin    
        if (rising_edge(push_button)) then
            stage1 <= '1';
        end if;
        if (falling_edge(push_button)) then
            stage2 <= stage1;
        end if;
    end process;
    ----------------------

      -- simulation process
    tb : process
    begin
        wait for (5 ns);
        pulse_loop : loop
            wait for (100 ns);
            push_button <= '1';
            wait for (100 ns);
            push_button <= '0';
            wait for (100 ns);
        end loop pulse_loop;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I just want to point out that it's really difficult as a human to see a LED blink by going dark for 100 ns.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Haha! Yes it is. Of course the simulation time has nothing to do with the actual circuit. It was just a behavioral test. I tend to copy and paste my vhdl templates. As long as the OP holds his push button down for longer than 100 ns, I think we'll be alright.

Comment: @HarrySvensson By the way, my comment to your answer was not intended as slight. I was trying to be friendly, in case you wanted to update your circuit. I missed the fact that the two LEDs was intentional.

Comment: I took your comment in a very hostile manner. I'm calling the cops. //Jöke //Juvenile ;)

Comment: This only works if you properly debounce the push button.

Comment: @Blup1980 Yes. I recognized that and planned to add it, but then forgot. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll fix it tomorrow.

Comment: @Blup1980 Debounce added.

Comment: Hi Blair. I'm reviewing answers and I wrote that: "I'll have to fit the device into a small cylinder (dia. 15mm, height 10-20 mm.)". I've been trying to review components and as far as I can see, the components used in your schematics will not fit the demands regarding size, would you agree?

Comment: @EibergDK No, these come in at least a couple of packages that would fit fine. Search for tssop.

Comment: @EibergDK Also notice that the two flip flops are in a single package. The inverter could be replaced by a single transistor, although it's not necessary- it would fit either way.

Comment: @EibergDK there you go. While this answer would work fine, I posted an alternate answer - microcontroller. Tiny, 1 chip, 8-pin solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a schematic I came up with, it's derived from a XNOR gate. I won't go into much details about how I solved it, but I'll highlight the things that are very important. The RC constant on the left side must be lower than the RC constant on the right side.

\$100k*10nF < 100k*22nF\$

That way the left side will charge up slower and have a lower voltage which will activate the correct P-mosfet.

[image]

It doesn't work exactly as you described, but it will work as a seal thingy. If you want it to be more like you described, then remove the left LED and its resistor from the schematic.

If you want to play around with the schematic, then [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000001+3.5993318835628396+58+5+50%0Af+688+368+736+368+1+1.5+0.02%0Af+672+368+624+368+1+1.5+0.02%0Aw+672+368+736+416+0%0Aw+688+368+624+416+0%0Aw+624+384+624+416+0%0Aw+736+384+736+416+0%0Aw+624+352+624+320+0%0Aw+736+352+736+320+0%0Ar+624+464+624+512+0+1000%0Ar+736+464+736+512+0+1000%0Ag+736+512+736+528+0%0Ag+624+512+624+528+0%0Ac+560+416+560+464+0+1e-8+2.955362049903842%0Aw+624+416+560+416+2%0Ag+560+464+560+480+0%0Ag+800+464+800+480+0%0Aw+800+416+736+416+2%0Ac+800+416+800+464+0+2.2000000000000002e-8+0.002978646449637459%0Aw+624+320+736+320+0%0A162+624+416+624+464+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0A162+736+416+736+464+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Aw+800+416+864+416+0%0Ar+864+416+864+464+0+100000%0Ag+864+464+864+480+0%0Ar+496+416+496+464+0+100000%0Ag+496+464+496+480+0%0Aw+496+416+560+416+0%0As+624+256+624+320+0+0+false%0AR+624+256+624+208+0+0+40+3+0+0+0.5%0As+736+320+800+320+0+1+false%0Ar+800+416+800+320+0+1000%0Ax+490+294+605+316+4+16+Plug%5Csin%5Csbattery%5C%5Cnswitch%0Ax+717+295+824+298+4+16+button%5Csswitch%0Ax+458+560+664+601+4+16+Left%5CsLED:%5C%5CnPlugged%5Csin%5Csbattery%5Csand%5Cs%5C%5Cnnever%5Cspressed%5Csthe%5Csbutton.%0Ax+730+560+929+620+4+16+Right%5CsLED:%5C%5CnPlugged%5Csin%5Csbattery%5Csand%5Cs%5C%5Cnone%5Csmoment%5Csin%5Cstime%5CsI%5C%5Cnhave%5Cspressed%5Csthe%5Csbutton.%0Ao+21+8+0+4099+1.25+0.00009765625+0+2+21+3%0A) you go.

Here's some links you might be interested in at **digikey**:

[P-mosfet with Vgs between 450mV to 2.5V](https://www.digikey.se/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278) (Vgs needs to be low so you can open and close the gate while being fed 3 volts).

[Dual P-mosfet if space is very much of a concern.](https://www.digikey.se/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-arrays/289?k=&pkeyword=&pv1236=189&pv1236=761&pv1236=716&pv1236=40&pv1236=758&pv1236=763&pv1236=718&pv1236=42&pv1236=760&pv1236=82&pv1236=739&pv1236=75&pv1236=192&pv1236=13&pv1236=221&pv1236=305&pv1236=72&pv1236=169&pv1236=290&pv1236=48&pv1236=12&pv1236=738&pv1236=177&pv1236=197&pv1236=343&pv1236=240&pv1236=551&pv1236=172&pv1236=23&pv1236=186&pv1236=411&pv1236=16&pv1236=370&pv1236=18&pv1236=17&pv1236=267&pv1236=387&pv1236=506&pv1236=294&pv1236=24&pv1236=25&pv1236=11&pv1236=7&pv1236=468&pv1236=27&pv1236=433&pv1236=251&pv1236=6&pv1236=4&pv1236=485&pv1236=20&pv1236=21&pv1236=130&pv1236=510&pv1236=80&pv1236=194&pv1236=133&pv1236=134&pv1236=3&pv1236=2&FV=ffe00121%2C9780005&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)

My favorite P-mosfet is [AO3401](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401.pdf), and you can get it [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1000PCS-AO3401-A19T-SOT-23-P-Channel-Mosfet-Transistor/32713692124.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.MSsDSk) from **aliexpress**. And yes, the AO3401 would work for you in the schematic above.

If you believe that this is the answer to your question (or the best you'll get), then mark it as an answer to your question.

---

### EDIT

Blair Fonville commented on this answer saying it was not correct, and he was right. And I don't like leaving things half-done, so here's one schematic that actually does exactly as OP wanted it to do.

[image]

Don't take the graph to heart and all that, but you will roughly see a 0.5 second blink. In the graph in the image just above, each division is 500 ms. The upper graph is the left branch that says 3v, the middle graph is the right branch that says 231.5 mV, the bottom graph is the LED.

In this schematic I flipped it horizontally, so as before the left RC should be smaller than right RC. This time left RC should be larger than right RC. Also, if you want longer blinks then increase the capacitor value, shorter blink then reduce. If there's any questions at all, make a comment.

And here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000009999999999999999%2027.727228452313398%2055%205%2050%0Ax%20-47%20182%204%20204%204%2016%20button%5C%5Cnswitch%0Af%20144%20176%2080%20176%201%201.5%200.02%0Af%20320%20176%20384%20176%201%201.5%200.02%0Aw%2080%20192%2080%20224%200%0Aw%20384%20192%20384%20224%200%0Aw%2080%20160%2080%20144%200%0Aw%20384%20160%20384%20144%200%0Aw%20384%20144%2080%20144%200%0Aw%20320%20224%20384%20224%202%0Aw%20144%20224%2080%20224%202%0Ag%20384%20272%20384%20288%200%0Ar%20384%20224%20384%20272%200%20100000%0Ag%2080%20272%2080%20288%200%0Ar%2080%20224%2080%20272%200%20100000%0Ag%20144%20272%20144%20288%200%0Ac%20144%20224%20144%20272%200%200.0000047%200.23554576180386025%0Aw%20144%20176%20256%20224%200%0Aw%20320%20176%20208%20224%200%0A162%20512%20256%20512%20304%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20512%20256%20512%20208%200%20100%0AR%2080%2080%2080%2048%200%200%2040%203%200%200%200.5%0As%2080%2080%2080%20144%200%200%20false%0As%2016%20144%2016%20224%200%201%20false%0Ar%2016%20224%2080%20224%200%20100000%0Aw%2016%20144%2080%20144%200%0Ax%2098%20108%20213%20130%204%2016%20Plug%5Csin%5Csbattery%5C%5Cnswitch%0Aw%20448%20144%20384%20144%200%0Af%20448%20192%20512%20192%201%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20512%20176%20512%20144%200%0Ar%20448%20144%20448%20192%200%201000000%0Ac%20320%20224%20320%20272%200%200.0000022%202.998813629243853%0Ag%20320%20272%20320%20288%200%0Aw%20448%20144%20512%20144%200%0Ad%20256%20256%20256%20224%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20208%20256%20208%20224%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20208%20224%20144%20224%200%0Aw%20256%20224%20320%20224%200%0Aw%20208%20256%20256%20256%200%0Aw%20448%20192%20448%20320%200%0Aw%20256%20256%20256%20320%200%0Aw%20256%20320%20448%20320%200%0Ag%20512%20304%20512%20320%200%0Ao%209%201024%200%204099%200.625%200.00009765625%200%202%209%203%0Ao%208%201024%200%204099%205%200.00009765625%200%202%208%203%0Ao%2018%201024%200%204099%202.5%200.0125%200%202%2018%203%0A) to the schematic if you want to play around. 
I strongly advice whoever that clicks the link to go to options > other options > time step. And set time step to like 500n and 50n IF you are going to mess with the capacitor values.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, a tiny microcontroller would work. For example, an ATtiny45/V in a tssop package would fit easily into your size requirements. It can accept the switch or trigger, denounce it, program the LED, and whatever else you want. You would just need to supply power. Use the internal oscillator for the clock.

[ATtiny45/V datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf)

[image: tssop ATtiny45]

Answer (score -1):

This meets all your requirements except the last one.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffeutF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The last one is what makes it tricky :)

Comment: What is the circuit for?

Comment: You could say it's a kind of sealing :)

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using "Normally closed switch"... check this for explanation...
https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-normally-closed-switch-work

https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/40pcs-Tact-Switch-NC-normally-closed-switch-imports-3-6-patch-soft-button-3-6-2/1850300_32715206548.html

The using this switch the circuit will be active normally. But when switch is pressed.. the circuit will be broken.

Comment: You didn't supply any schematic. However, assuming you simply put that switch in series with the power and LED, it does not meet the last in the OP's list of requirements, which is: "It should no longer be possible to turn off the LED unless battery is removed".